# Need help loading staticfiles with nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, deployment

I am having trouble loading the static files from my django project.
Here is a picture of my directories:
[DIRECTORIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Rs8.png)

I have ran **docker-compose up** and I get the following errors:
[ERROR IMAGES ON BROWSER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxF2y.png)

Here is what my nginx (default.conf) file looks like:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log

        location / {
            root /frontend/templates/frontend
            # proxy_pass http://pathfinder_gunicorn;
            # include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /static/;
        }

        location ~ \.(css)$ {
            root /frontend/static/css;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the entire directory looks like relative to my nginx (default.conf) file:
[ALL DIRECTORIES WITH DOCKER FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYwFT.png)

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile and also share the location of static files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Container not loading static files from Django-React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139020/docker-container-not-loading-static-files-from-django-react-project)

Comment: Please build one good answerable question instead of multiple partial questions about the same issue.

Comment: The question is off-topic on SO